# how to combine two themes in android

Tags: android, android-manifest

Can someone please tell me how to combine two theme values(Ex:`@android:style/Theme.Dialog` and `@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar`) for `android:theme` attribute in manifest file.

Thanks,
venu

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to create custom theme. I created a custom theme to combine both `@android:style/Theme.Dialog` and `@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar` as below
 `<style parent="android:style/Theme.Dialog" name="Theme.NoTitleBar.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>`

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Comment: thanx for your reply. I want to show my activity as a dialog without title bar.